# Sending Cyrillic characters to Word with PHP and COM Object

Tags: php, com, internationalization

I am building a PHP application which needs to create a Word Document by the means of COM objects. I found most of the required functions by checking the code of recorded test Macros, but i still can't find the write way to pass Cyrillic characters. I am trying the following:

```
$word->Selection->TypeText(ChrW(1091) & ChrW(1085) & ChrW(1080) & ChrW(1074) & ChrW(1077) & ChrW(1088) & ChrW(1089) & ChrW(1080) & ChrW(1090) & ChrW(1077) & ChrW(1090));
```

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ChrW() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\COM\test.php on line 42

Unfortunately i cannot find any documentation for the COM objects especially for PHP, so i am placing my question here with hope that someone can assist me with that.

Comment: Have you tried using UTF-8 encoding in your Php file, and entering the cyrillic characters directly?

Comment: Yes i've done that and it didn't work

Comment: That's not a lot to work with. What exactly happened when you tried?

Comment: I am getting strange symbols in my word document:

ÑƒÐ½Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ€ÑÐ¸Ñ‚ÐµÑ

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar problem with sending Māori characters to Word using PHP and COM.  The answer was in how I created the COM object:

```
$wordApp = new COM("word.application", null, CP_UTF8); // <-- Important to specify codepage CP_UTF8
// Open document...
...
$text = "Chars with macrons: Ā ā Ē ē Ī ī Ō ō Ū ū"; // UTF-8 string
$wordApp->Selection->TypeText($text);
...
```

The third parameter to COM is the **codepage** and it specifies what conversion to use on strings passed to/from the COM object.  By specifying **CP_UTF8**, I'm telling COM that all strings that I will pass in (like `$text` in `$wordApp->Selection->TypeText($text);`) will be encoded using UTF-8 and all strings I receive, I want encoded using UTF-8. If you don't specify the codepage, the default is used, probably Windows-1252 (Western).

For more details check here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting strange symbols in my word document: ÑƒÐ½Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ€ÑÐ¸Ñ‚ÐµÑ

I'm not sure what the Word document's character set is and what the recommended method to do this is.

In absence of any authoritative info on that, I would try to feed it the data and convert between character sets until it works.

Make sure your PHP file is UTF-8 encoded and then try

```
$text = "Привет, как дела";

$word->Selection->TypeText(iconv("utf-8", "utf-8", $text);       // no conversion
$word->Selection->TypeText(iconv("utf-8", "iso-8859-5", $text);  // cyrillic codepage
$word->Selection->TypeText(iconv("utf-8", "utf-16", $text);  // not sure whether this will work
```

one of these may work for you, depending on what the document's character encoding is.

There may be a COM method to define the document's encoding. If there is, it would be the ideal way to use that and set the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: That didn't work either, but i think there is a progress. I am getting three different results by the three different methods:

First:
Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚

Second:
âÕáâ

Third:
þÿ B 5 A B

Comment: @Stoyan Then try the encodings from this list: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/encoding-standards-for-opening-and-saving-files-HP005258454.aspx I would start with `Windows-1251`

Comment: I just tried Windows-1251 and i am still getting different symbol results. I think the problem might be within the initial format in the php file

Comment: @Stoyan the PHP file needs to be UTF-8 encoded for this to work.

Comment: Yes i got 

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>

in the beginning of my file

Comment: @Stoyan that's just for the browser, it won't have any effect on what we do. The file must be UTF-8 encoded in your text editor or IDE (the setting is often in the "Save as..." dialog)

Comment: @Stoyan Hmm, too bad. I would try all the encodings mentioned in the list above, but if that doesn't work, I can't think of any more options

Comment: I guess the problem here is that it might not be possible to send this type of text through the COM object

Comment: @Stoyan COM seems to have a "codepage" parameter, see http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php what happens if you set that to UTF-8 (and enter the text directly, without `iconv()`?)

Comment: I am not really sure how to do that

Comment: @Stoyan can you show the full code you are using to initialize the COM object